# Asynchronous listener in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

```
      Task task1=  firestore.collection(collection).document(city).collection("Bigads").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

            if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                if (task1.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                } else {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot docs : task.getResult()) {

                        AdsModel ad = new AdsModel(docs.getString("For"), docs.getString("ImageURL"), docs.getString(" Product"), docs.getString("ShopUID"));

                        Bdata.add(ad);
                        homeMainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        recent_show_all.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rvd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        recentRView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        end.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

            } else {


            }

        }
    });
```

> In task2 their is one if condition where i need to check task1 is empty or not .both listeners are asynchronous if task2 run before task1 then the if condition will become true and the result will be wrong , How to handle this task so that task1 should run first then task2?

```
Task task2= firestore.collection("user").document(uid).collection("rvd").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {


                if (task.isSuccessful() && task1.getResult().isEmpty()) {      



                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {

                        RvdModel r = new RvdModel(doc.get("image1").toString(), doc.get("ProductUID").toString(), doc.get("Brand").toString());
                        Rdata.add(r);
                        rvdAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        suggestionRView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        suggest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        suggest_show_all.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "errororr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: try using rx-java, it's will resolve your issue

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: will u please explain as a code @GianhTran

Comment: because its an asynchronous listener and i dont know how to handle tasks @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @user175799 now I am just give you a key, you should try it first. That's very hard to understand if you have no base about rx-java. Let's try it https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `Task2` inside `onComplete` of `Task1`

```
  Task task1=  firestore.collection(collection).document(city).collection("Bigads").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        // On task1 success do some stuff 
        // Call task2 here after ensure task.getResult().isEmpty().
     if (task.getResult().isEmpty()){
          Task task2= firestore.collection("user").document(uid).collection("rvd").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {  
            // Do some stuff... 
            }
  }
 }
```